# How to link/match each data of a column to every data of another column to create new set of data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From the image, I want to match each data in columnA to every data in columnC to create new set of data like column E and F. Is there any easy way to do this instead of copy and paste.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed : a better copy n paste (less formula,less fuss).

In F2 put `=OFFSET($C$1,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA($C:$C)-1)+1,0)`.

Then put `=IFERROR(IF(ROW()-1<=(COUNTA(A:A)-1)*(COUNTA(C:C)-1),OFFSET($A$1,COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2),0),"done"),"")` in E2.

Drag both downwards.

Once you get "done" in column E, it means you had listed all the possible combination.

It should works now. God willing. ( :

Idea : use row()&mod() and countif() to generate a counter/reference number. then load individual entry using offset.

Comment: Thank you. I have problem when I drag "=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2))" in E2, then drag till E7. The message shows up that microsoft cannot calculate formula. There is a circular reference in a open workbook. What should I do?

Comment: Which 2 cells does the arrow points to ? Is there any formula in column A & C ? (Mine doesn't) if you don't mind.. you may share the sample file for troubleshooting..

Comment: I had posted my correction. sorry for my earlier error.

Comment: added some theoretical description...  ( :